Problem with simplification of this indefinite integral
Let's consider this fairly easy problem.
$$\int \sin x \cos x dx$$
which can be transformed into
$$\dfrac12 \int \sin 2x \ dx$$
Setting $t = 2x$, we have $dt/dx = 2$
Substituting this value into our equation
$$\dfrac 12 \int \sin t \ dt = -\dfrac 14 \cos 2x + C$$
Now using an alternative method to solve this Equation
Assume $$t = \sin x \\ dt/dx = \cos x \\ dt = \cos x \ dx$$
Looking back at the original integral
$$\int \sin x \cos x dx \\ \int t \ dt = \dfrac {(t^2)}{2} \\ = \dfrac {\sin^2 x}{2}+C$$
I dont seem to find any calculation mistakes as such or perhaps my fundamentals of integrals itself aren't all that clear. But it would be of great help if someone could clarify this for me

Use MathJax, please.

You have done this error : $dx/dt = 1/2$

Besides, I have begun to "Latexify" your text. Take it as a model for next time.

Don't forget the $\Huge{+C}$ appearing in all indefinite integrals.

The point of my comment was not to urge you to add those $C$s, but to make you realize that they are the explanation to apparently "different" answers. Pro tip: plot those different answers!

Note that
$$-\frac14 \cos(2x) +c = -\frac14 (\cos^2x-\sin^2x)+c=-\frac14(1-2\sin^2x)+c=\frac12\sin^2x+c',$$
where $c'=c-\frac14$.

Hint:
Rewrite the identity of $\cos 2x$ in terms of sine only, then solve for the squared term.

That is $$\cos 2x = 1- 2 \sin^2 x$$ hence $$\sin^2 x  = \dfrac 12 (1 - \cos 2x)$$

